# can we Enable theme customization in wordpress multi site feature for sub domain

Tags: wordpress, themes

Currently i am working on wordpress multi site feature, where we have 1 wp installation and many blogs uses that installation, but limit is that there is a limited feature for sub domain, so i want to enable theme customization feature to sub domain, if any one has any idea???

Answer (score 0):

Pick themes that have extensive customization features in the admin area - NOT via editing theme files.